I dont redirect any of page but project stuck "/login" page
I'm using nuxtjs and I have problem here, its stuck on error page and contains a text 404 Page not found: /login but I don't have a login file. I'm using prisma, supabase in this project. its here github link https://github.com/serhasHacizade/clone-projects/tree/main/threads-clone
Here are my files:
pages/auth.vue
<template>
    <div id="auth-page" class="w-full h-[100vh] pt-32">
        <div class="w-full">
            <div class="w-full flex items-center justify-center gap-2.5 p-2">
                <img class="w-[35px]" src="/threads-logo.png" alt="">
                <span class="font-bold text-2xl text-white">Threads</span>
            </div>
            <div class="max-w-[350px] mx-auto px-2 text-white">
                <div class="text-center mb-6 mt-4">Login / Register</div>
                <button class="flex items-center justify-center gap-3 p-1.5 w-full border 
                rounded-full text-lg font-semibold" @click="login('github')">
                    <div class="flex items-center gap-2 justify-center">
                        <img class="w-full max-w-[30px] rounded-full" src="/github-logo.png" alt="">
                        Github
                    </div>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
const client = useSupabaseClient();
const user = useSupabaseUser();
watchEffect(() => {
    if (user.value) {
        return navigateTo("/")
    }
});
const login = async (prov) => {
    const {data, error} = await client.auth.signInWithOAuth({
        provider: prov,
        redirectTo: window.location.prigin
    })
    if (error) console.log(error);
};
</script>

nuxt.config.ts
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  pages: true,
  modules: [
    "nuxt-icon",
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss",
    "@nuxtjs/supabase",
    "@pinia/nuxt",
    "@vite-pwa/nuxt",
  ],
  runtimeConfig: {
    public: {
      bucketUrl: process.env.BUCKET_URL
    }
  },
  devtools: { enabled: false }
})


You need to create the login page to use supabase - https://supabase.nuxtjs.org/authentication#log-in-page-login

Nah, you should rather set the redirection path on Supabase's side. It's a config issue for the successful connection.

i create login.vue and confirm.vue files. the issue is gone but i cant move another page again. if you want all my project link

By default, the module is implementing a redirect middleware. All pages of your application are automatically redirected to the login page. Follow this docs https://supabase.nuxtjs.org/usage/composables/usesupabaseuser#auth-middleware
If you want to exclude redirect to /login page. You need to add extra config in your nuxt.config.ts by following this redirect options.
